# How to know if specific row is empty in Android SQlite database

Tags: android

I have to retrieve `Sqlite` database table rows of images.But some rows have no data , that is empty columns are there is database tables.

Here  is my database table image

[image]

In the above image , there is one `ProfilePICURL` column some rows have no data.I have check the length of retrieve `ProfilePICURL` string , but not work.So how can i check the row is null. Thanks.

Here is my retrieve method

```
public void LoadProfilePics()
            {
                db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();

                Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from Inspector ", null);
                if (cursor.moveToFirst())
                {
                do {

                String strProfile_Pics = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ProfilePICURL"));
                String strDownLoadStatus = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("DownLoadStatus"));
                if(strDownLoadStatus.equals("0") && strProfile_Pics.length() != 0)
                {
                    String URL_downLoadProfilePic = namespace + "/DownloadFile/FilePathMobile/PROFILEPICPATH/FileName/" + strProfile_Pics;
                    newFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + File.separator + "classNKK_ProfilePic");
                    download_PngFileImgLoader(URL_downLoadProfilePic, newFolder, strProfile_Pics);
                    updatedArrayList.add(strProfile_Pics);
                    Log.e("URL_downLoadProfilePic ", " ==========>" + URL_downLoadProfilePic);

                }

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();

            }
```

Comment: Why not use a `WHERE` clause in the query itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
     String strProfile_Pics = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ProfilePICURL"));
       if(strDownLoadStatus.equals("0") && 
            strProfile_Pics != null && 
               !strProfile_Pics.trim().isEmpty()){
         //do stuff
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
  Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from Inspector where profilePICURL IS NULL ", null);
```

This query will return all the empty/null rows of Profile pic Url.

Comment: I don't have to retrieve empty/null rows of Profile pic.I want to avoid empty/null rows while download the  Profile pic.